# ASP.NET MVC login page returns 401 (unauthorized access) after publishing to hosting provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

In order to provide secure access to some administrative backend for a very restricted group of users I used forms based authentication to some secured controller actions. In my case web.config contains something like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" timeout="2880">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
       <user name="some-user" password="fb223245bd5488866347724c2c95dbe4bb5ac906"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

As I don't need membership providers and the user is hard coded, membership (and roles) is not configured.

This worked fine in my development environment (VS2010 + integrated web server) until I published the site to the hosting provider. Now everytime I navigate to the User/Login action the server returns errorcode 401 - unauthorized access.

Any idea how to solve this problem? Are there any IIS configuration issues?

Hosting Environment:
* IIS 7
* .NET 4.0 / ASP.NET 4.0 MVC2 enabled

thanks in advance, Reinhard

Comment: What about Authorization configuration section? what is there?

Comment: I use the [AuthorizeAttribute]. I think that this essentially does the same as the authorization section (correct me if I'm wrong)...

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/137073/401-unauthorized-on-server-2008-r2-iis-7-5), and this [related blog post](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2011/09/06/fix401-unauthorized-access-is-denied-due-to-invalid-credentials-on-asp-net-mvc-iis-7/).